# What is the type for structure and pointers?

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following code:

```
struct client {
     char buf[MAXLINE];
     int curp;
};
struct client *c;
```

I want to know what is the type of each of the following variables and why?

```
x1 = c->buf;
x2 = *c->buf;
x3 = &c->buf[c->curp];
x4 = *c;
```

I know that c is a pointer to struct client. Thus x4 after dereferencing should be struct client.

Comment: Continue like this, for `x1` to `x3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible types as,

x1 = c->buf;

x1 is pointer to a character since buf is the base pointer.

x2 = *c->buf;

x2 is a character since base pointer is dereferenced to get the first character

x3 = &c->buf[c->curp];

x3 is a pointer to a character since c->buf[c->curp] gives a character and `&` gives its address

x4 = *c;

x4 is a variable of struct client since c is a pointer to a variable of that struct and is dereferenced.

It is not necessary since other types can also be used to hold these values. these are possible types.

Comment: Turns out you are just speculating. `int x1, x2, x3;` compiles just fine. As does `void* x1; double x2; volatile const signed long long* volatile x3;` for that matter...

Comment: @Lundin i did mention that `other types can also be used to hold these values`. like for pointer void * variable assignment is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code actually compiles... then:

> x1 = c->buf;

x1 could be anything, as the rvalue of the expression doesn't affect or determine the type of x1.

c->buf is an array, which in turn decays into pointer. A pointer can be converted to any other pointer type. And it can be converted to an int.

> x2 = *c->buf;

x2 could be anything, as the rvalue of the expression doesn't affect or determine the type of x2.

*c->buf is a `char`, but that type can be converted to any other integer type and also to pointer types or floating point etc etc.

> x3 = &c->buf[c->curp];

x3 could be anything, as the rvalue of the expression doesn't affect or determine the type of x3.

For the same reasons as for x1, except the rvalue in this case is a char pointer.

> x4 = *c;

x4 could be anything, as the rvalue of the expression doesn't affect or determine the type of x4.

However, *c is a struct, so x4 would have to be another struct or the code wouldn't compile.